# I want to get ws rpc url with the docker image for our substrate node

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker, wss

I'm in the process of creating a Docker image for our `Substrate-node`, and I used that following method to accomplish it.

```
# This is an example build stage for the node template. Here we create the binary in a temporary image.

# This is a base image to build substrate nodes
FROM docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production as builder

WORKDIR /node-template
COPY . .
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/rustup /usr/local/cargo && \
    curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y --default-toolchain none && \
    rustup show && \
    cargo build --release

# This is the 2nd stage: a very small image where we copy the binary."
FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04
LABEL description="Multistage Docker image for Substrate Node Template" \
  image.type="builder" \
  image.authors="alan.ma.dapps@gmail.com" \
  image.vendor="Substrate Developer Hub" \
  image.description="Multistage Docker image for Substrate Node Template" \
  image.source="https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template" \
  image.documentation="https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template"

# Copy the node binary.
COPY --from=builder /node-template/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin

RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -U -s /bin/sh -d /node-dev node-dev && \
  mkdir -p /chain-data /node-dev/.local/share && \
  chown -R node-dev:node-dev /chain-data && \
  ln -s /chain-data /node-dev/.local/share/node-template && \
  # unclutter and minimize the attack surface
  rm -rf /usr/bin /usr/sbin && \
  # check if executable works in this container
  /usr/local/bin/node-template --version

USER node-dev

EXPOSE 30333 9933 9944 9615
VOLUME ["/chain-data"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/node-template"]
```

And I got the image successfully.
So I run it using this command.

```
docker run -it -p 9944:9944 wolfmorgan/substrate-node
```

Now I got `Running JSON-RPC server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944`, but I want to get `Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["*"]`

How can I build a docker image to get this?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/node-template", "--dev", "--ws-external"`, but got `--ws-external arg not found`

Comment: Try `--unsafe-ws-external`

Comment: I got `error: unexpected argument '--unsafe-ws-external' found`

Comment: So I tried `--unsafe-rpc-external` instead of `--unsafe-ws-external`. But I couldn't get the result what I wanted - `Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["*"]`. Just I got `Running JSON-RPC server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944`

Comment: Hi @AlanMa, running `node-template --dev` should start the rpc server listening in `127.0.0.1:9944`, from which `tag` are you compiling the node?

Comment: I can run it on local successfully, and got the ws rpc. Just I am struggling to get it after built a docker image for the substrate node. @pepoviola

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `--rpc-cors=all` to achieve `allowed origins=["*"]`.

Here is the explanation for the flag:

```
$ substrate --help
...
      --rpc-cors <ORIGINS>
          Specify browser Origins allowed to access the HTTP & WS RPC servers.

          A comma-separated list of origins (protocol://domain or special `null` value). 
          Value of `all` will disable origin validation. 
          Default is to allow localhost and <https://polkadot.js.org> origins. 
          When running in --dev mode the default is to allow all origins.
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @btwiuse. But I got already `allowed origins=["*"]`.
Like this. `Running JSON-RPC server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["*"]`. But I want to run `JSON-RPC WS server` instead of `JSON-RPC server`. Like this `Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["*"]`

Comment: @AlanMa It is already a WS server regardless of the log message

Comment: But I couldn't connect with the substrate node using `ws://127.0.0.1:9944` @btwiuse.

Comment: `Error Connecting to Substrate
Connection to websocket 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed.`